# Is clone copy-on-write?

Tags: php, imagick

When I clone an `Imagick` object using the `clone` operator, which one is the expensive operation, the `clone` or the subsequent write to the clone?

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('some_big_image.jpg');

$new_image = clone $image; // is this an expensive operation?
```

Comment: *expensive* in what sense?

Comment: CPU and RAM, what else? :)

Comment: @Dagon 'expensive' has a particular 'term of art' meaning in computer science, which you probably ought to learn about if you're answering so many questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Danack thanks point me to a definitive definition.

Comment: @Dagon There is no definitive definition; interpreting cost can vary based on what resources you consider expensive. However in PHP clones can be 'cheap' where references to variables just have a reference counter incremented. Or in this case actual work is done, which is more 'expensive'.

Comment: @Danack so then asking for the OP's definition made complete sense - no?

Comment: No, the question was clear in terms of PHP operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some testing with Imagick 3.3.0RC2 built with ImageMagick 6.8.9 on Windows 7 gave these results:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setResolution(1000,1000);

// This is a vector image, to make sure it's not just memory-mapped or something like that
$image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/test.eps'));

$new_image = clone $image;                                         // 0.012 s  
$new_image->floodFillPaintImage('black', 0, 'white', 0, 0, false); // 0.179 s
$image->floodFillPaintImage('black', 0, 'white', 0, 0, false);     // 0.126 s
```

(I ran this in a loop, the given durations are on avarage.)

From these numbers it seems like `clone` is very cheap compared to the subsequent write.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the clone method on an Imagick object does do actual work, as opposed to just increasing an internal reference counter.

In particular it calls `CloneMagickWand` in the underlying ImageMagick library. That does copy the 'image' - however ImageMagick does not always hold all pixels for an image in memory. So exactly how much work it does is not obvious and probably depends on how you have ImageMagick configured.

The expense of the subsequent write will depend on the function used. Setting a new format for the image does not very much until the image is saved. Doing a blur of the image does a (obviously) a lot of work.

Comment: Helpful answer. I did [some experiments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449027/is-clone-copy-on-write#32449940) to find out how much work is actually done.